# Read and understand contents of AMR file on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, signal-processing

I want to open an AMR file so I can perform signal processing algorithms on the contents (ex: what is the pitch?). I know you can open these files in a media player, but I want to get the actual contents of the file.

At one point I printed the contents and got a bunch of integers, but have no idea what they mean.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are able to get at the data, but don't know very much at all about the basics of audio signal processing.

The data you are looking at is probably raw bytes that need to be translated into PCM (Pulse Code Modulation). The Java [Overview of the Sampled Package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/sampled-overview.html) talks a bit about the relationship of the bytes to PCM as determined by a specific format.

For example, if the format specifies 16-bit encoding, then two bytes (each being 8 bits) will be concatenated to form a single PCM value that will range from -32767 to 32767. (Some people work directly with these numbers, others scale the numbers to floats ranging from -1 to 1).

And if the file is 44100 fps, then there will be 44100 "frames" of data per second, where the frame will most likely be mono or stereo (one PCM or two PCM values per frame)

The tutorial does get into Java specifics pretty quickly, but at least it gives a basic picture and you will have more terms to use in a search for something more specific to Android.

If you want to go into greater depth or detail, you could consult Steve Smith's [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://dspguide.com/). It is a free online book that I've found to be extremely helpful.

EDIT:
AMR is a format that employs compression, so deriving the PCM will require conversion step. From what I'm reading [What is an AMR File?](https://www.lifewire.com/amr-file-2619620), *Audacity* can be used to convert to **.wav**, after which Java can be used to import and obtain the PCM.